# Empty crontab when crontab -e

Tags: cron

I am logged in as root on my CentOs.

If I do `crontab -e`, I have an empty file.

If I do `cat /etc/crontab`, I have a file with commands in it.

How is it possible?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you see if you do `crontab -l`?

Comment: Do you have any cron-jobs for other users? The files for the specific users are stored in "/var/spool/cron/<user>". Or you can do "crontab -u <user> -l" to list cron-jobs for a specified user.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. When I "crontab -l" I have a "no crontab for root" ... And about /var/spool/cron there is no directory or file ... Any idea ?

Comment: Did U solve this? I have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [there](https://superuser.com/questions/290093/difference-between-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e), `/etc/crontab` is for the system crontab, while the `crontab` command is for the user crontabs which are stored in the files `/var/spool/cron/<username>`.